# Layout in Rascal

Tags: rascal

When I import the Lisra recipe,

```
import demo::lang::Lisra::Syntax;
```

This creates the syntax:

```
layout Whitespace      = [\t-\n\r\ ]*; 
lexical IntegerLiteral = [0-9]+ !>> [0-9];
lexical AtomExp        = (![0-9()\t-\n\r\ ])+ !>>  ![0-9()\t-\n\r\ ];

start syntax LispExp
      = IntegerLiteral
      | AtomExp
      | "(" LispExp* ")"
      ;
```

Through the `start syntax`-definition, layout should be ignored around the input when it is parsed, as is stated in the documentation: http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Declarations/SyntaxDefinition/SyntaxDefinition.html

However, when I type:

```
rascal>(LispExp)` (something)`
```

This gives me a `concrete syntax fragment` error (or a `ParseError` when using the `parse`-function), in contrast to:

```
rascal>(LispExp)`(something)`
```

Which succesfully parses. I tried this both with one of the latest versions of Rascal as well as the Eclipse plugin version.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Thank you.

Ps. Lisra's `parse`-function:

```
public Lval parse(str txt) = build(parse(#LispExp, txt));
```

Also fails on the example:

```
rascal>parse(" (something)")
|project://rascal/src/org/rascalmpl/library/ParseTree.rsc|(10329,833,<253,0>,<279,60>): ParseError(|unknown:///|(0,1,<1,0>,<1,1>))
    at *** somewhere ***(|project://rascal/src/org/rascalmpl/library/ParseTree.rsc|(10329,833,<253,0>,<279,60>))
    at parse(|project://rascal/src/org/rascalmpl/library/demo/lang/Lisra/Parse.rsc|(163,3,<7,44>,<7,47>))
    at $shell$(|stdin:///|(0,13,<1,0>,<1,13>))
```

Comment: My apologies, I missed that I have to use `start[LispExp]`... However, I believe that the `parse`-function in the Lisra recipe has a small bug nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a `start` non-terminal Rascal defines two non-terminals in one go:

```
rascal>start syntax A = "a";
ok
```

One non-terminal is `A`, the other is `start[A]`. Given a layout non-terminal in scope, say `L`, the latter is automatically defined by (something like) this rule:

```
syntax start[A] = L before A top L after;
```

If you call a parser or wish to parse a concrete fragment, you can use either non-terminal:

```
parse(#start[A], " a ") // parse using the start non-terminal and extra layout
parse(A, "a") // parse only an A
(start[A]) ` a ` // concrete fragment for the start-non-terminal
(A) `a` // concrete fragment for only an A
[start[A]] " a "
[A] "a"
```