# Error running ParseTree

Tags: rascal

In the Rascal shell, doing this:

```
import lang::c90::\syntax::C;
import ParseTree;
parse(#TranslationUnit, |file:///teste.c|);
```

I get in the stable standalone jar:

```
|prompt:///|(24,93,<1,24>,<1,117>): ParseError(|file:///home/rafael2k/files/UnB/static_analysis/eclipse-workspace/rascal-C/c-source/teste.c|(47,0,<4,0>,<4,0>))
        at parse(|prompt:///|(24,93,<1,24>,<1,117>))
        at *** somewhere ***(|prompt:///|(24,93,<1,24>,<1,117>))
        at parse(|prompt:///|(24,93,<1,24>,<1,117>))
```

And in Eclipse I get a giant message error:

```
(...)
  public AbstractStackNode<IConstructor>[] FloatingPointConstant() {
    return FloatingPointConstant.EXPECTS;
  }
  public AbstractStackNode<IConstructor>[] StructDeclarator() {
    return StructDeclarator.EXPECTS;
  }
}
Advice: |http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Errors/Static/JavaCompilation/JavaCompilation.html|null
```

Any tip?

Btw, running Debian Jessie, Oracle Java 1.8.0_112,x86_64.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be fixed with this:

```
parse(#start[TranslationUnit], |file:///teste.c|);
```

By using a start non-terminal you can parse files which begin and/or end with whitespace or source code comments. See also the answer to this question: [Layout in Rascal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205620/layout-in-rascal)

By the way, this grammar will parse c programs after the processor has been applied.

The Eclipse error is a seemingly unrelated issue for which we would love to receive a stack trace on the github issue tracker.

Comment: Only very simple programs are accepted. |prompt:///|(78,4,<1,78>,<1,82>): ParseError(|project://rascal-C/src/main.c|(0,1,<1,0>,<1,1>))
        at parse(|prompt:///|(78,4,<1,78>,<1,82>))
        at *** somewhere ***(|prompt:///|(78,4,<1,78>,<1,82>))
        at parse(|prompt:///|(78,4,<1,78>,<1,82>))

Comment: what does not work: "#include", multiline printf (I think no multiline string at all) and initialization of multiple variables multiline (ex: int i = 0,\nj = 0,\nk=0).

Comment: The grammar is for parsing programs after the preprocessor!

Comment: ahhh, did not know that. thanks!! the code of my experiments are here: https://github.com/rafael2k/rascal-C99