# Parsing files that start with comment using Rascal

Tags: parsing, ecmascript-6, rascal

I have the following ES6 file I am trying to parse:

```
// comment1

function sum(x, y) {
return x + y;
}

// comment2

var value = 22;
```

Parsing does not work for files that begin with comments, white spaces, new lines. It works for comments in all parts of the code. The error I get is:

```
[parsing file:] /test/function.js... found an error at line 3, column 0
```

The starting line for the grammar is:

```
start syntax CompilationUnit = Statement* statements LAYOUT?;
```

My LAYOUT definition is the following:

```
lexical LAYOUT
= Whitespace
| Comment
;

layout LAYOUTLIST
= LAYOUT*
!>> [\t\ \n]
!>> "/*"
!>> "//" ;
```

I have tried to add `LAYOUT?` and `LAYOUT*` to the beginning of the start syntax statement, but I got:

```
[parsing file:] /test/function.js|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(13348,964,<407,0>,<442,87>): Ambiguity(|unknown:///|(0,84,<1,0>,<10,0>),"CompilationUnit","//comment 1\n\nfunction sum(x, y) {\n    return x + y;\n}\n\n//akakakakak\n\nvar caio = 22;\n")
    at *** somewhere ***(|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(13348,964,<407,0>,<442,87>))
    at parse(|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(14305,5,<442,80>,<442,85>))
    at $root$(|prompt:///|(0,45,<1,0>,<1,45>))
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an automatic implicit rule generated for you:

```
start[CompilationUnit] = LAYOUTLIST CompilationUnit top LAYOUTLIST;
```

With this info you can deduce you need to call:

```
parse(#start[CompilationUnit], myFile)
```

You'll get a tree that includes the whitespace and comments before and after the start nonterminal. The 'top' field can be used to project the stuff in between the whitespace

Comment: There is a similar question and answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32206141/1768565